# template parameter with conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
bool func(const T1& t, const T2& t2) {
    return t == t2;
}


class Base {
public:
    bool operator ==(const Base&) const { return true;}
    Base(int y) : x(y) {}
    operator int() {
        return x;
    }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    func<long, Base>(4L, Base(5)); // not ok
    func<long, long>(4L, Base(5)); //ok
}
```

Can somebody elaborate why the first version does not work? In otherwords why does the binary operator == in func not use the conversion operator int to convert the template parameter bound to Base into int?

Is there anyway to make version 1 work by only modifying the class Base?

Comment: Note: You have two implicit conversions (the constructor and the operator). Make one 'explicit' (maybe the constructor) to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `func` accepts its parameters by const reference, but the `operator int()` defined in your `Base` class is a non-const member function. Mark it as a const member function, as shown below, and your code will compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
bool func(const T1& t, const T2& t2) {
    return t == t2;
}


class Base {
public:
    bool operator ==(const Base&) const { return true;}
    Base(int y) : x(y) {}
    operator int() const {
        return x;
    }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    func<long, Base>(4L, Base(5)); // ok now!
    func<long, long>(4L, Base(5)); // ok
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41a583c202f79a81)